# convert filepart to byteArray

Tags: arrays, spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

In my spring application, I am getting FilePart object and need to convert it to byteArray.

Below is my code.

```
val byteArray: ByteArray = file.content().map { it -> it.asInputStream().readBytes() }.blockLast()!!
```

But it is giving me error as

java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-kqueue-3

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [DataBufferUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBufferUtils.html#join-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-), the *join(...)* method offers a safe and efficient way to aggregate a data buffer stream into a single data buffer

```
Mono<byte[]> getByteArray(FilePart filePart) {
    return DataBufferUtils.join(filePart.content())
                          .map(dataBuffer -> dataBuffer.asByteBuffer().array());
}
```

Comment: byte[] is not same as ByteArray

Comment: you can easily initiate ByteArray with byte[] https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e12063/oracle/dss/util/xdo/common/io/ByteArray.html#ByteArray(byte[])